# Context Management in Bot Framework - Node JS

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

in the **main dialog**, I have used this to get the details of the user activity and session ID `stepContext.context._activity`
and *I am able to store the data in JSON format*, 
I want to know how to use the previous text of the user for the next query if there is no entity present in that and it should work for multiple users, not for a single user.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are simply wanting to know how to access input from a user from the previous step and use it in the current one?

Comment: Side note, `stepContext.context.activity` is the proper way to access the activity.

Comment: @StevenKanberg yes, and it should work for each and every user simultaneously without any ambiguity. and Thanks for the input on `stepContext.context.activity` this

Answer (score 2):

The location of the user's input varies depending on the option provided to them. Simple text input is available in the `stepContext.context.activity.text` field. However, the user's returned value could, for example, exist in:

- `stepContext.result`, if a hero card is used
- `stepContext.options`, if a value is forwarded on from a previous step or action
- `stepContext.context.activity.text`, if a suggested action is used
- `stepContext.context.activity.value`, if a postBack is returned

There are a few other possibilities. Referencing the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) is a good place to start as are the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) for getting a grasp on all the possibilities. Don't be averse to inspecting the `stepContext` to see how it is populated and with what.

```js
async firstStep(stepContext) {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity('Type something...');
    return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
}

async secondStep(stepContext) {
    const result = stepContext.context.activity.text;
    return await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`You said: ${ result }`);
```

Hope of help!